# Laravel form with dropzone saves twice to database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone

I have a model called **Masseur** and another model **MasseurImage** connected with a `belongsTo()` relationship. I also have a form with some basic inputs and Dropzone image upload integrated. The idea is when the *"Create new masseur"* form is submitted, it creates a new **Masseur** entry in the db, and creates many **MasseurImage** entries *(based on how many images has been added into the dropzone field)*.

---

Everything works fine, except the Masseur model is saved twice in the database after the form is submitted.

### View

```
<form method="post" id="etCreateMasseurForm" action="{{ route('masseur.add') }}" name="etCreateMasseurForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <input type="hidden" name="masseur_id" id="masseur_id">

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="nickname">Becenév</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="name">Név</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    </div>

    <div id="dropzoneDragArea" class="dropzone dz-default dz-message dropzoneDragArea form-control"></div>

</form>
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $masseur = Masseur::create($request->all());

        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            foreach ($request->file('file') as $file) {
                $filename = $file->store('public/files/'.$masseur->id);
                MasseurImage::create([
                    'masseur_id' => $masseur->id,
                    'filename' => $filename
                ]);
            }
        }
        
        return response()->json(['status' => "success", 'masseur_id'=> $masseur->id]);
    }
```

### Javascript

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $(function () {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneDragArea", {
            paramName: "file",
            url: "{{ route('masseur.add') }}",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            params: {
                _token: token
            },
            init: function () {
                var myDropzone = this;
                $("form[name='etCreateMasseurForm']").submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    URL = $("#etCreateMasseurForm").attr('action');
                    formData = $('#etCreateMasseurForm').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: URL,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.status == "success") {
                                var masseur_id = result.masseur_id;
                                $("#masseur_id").val(masseur_id);
                                myDropzone.processQueue();
                            } else {
                                console.log("error");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    let masseur_id = document.getElementById('masseur_id').value;
                    formData.append('masseur_id', masseur_id);
                });
                this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    window.location.href = "/";
                });
                this.on("queuecomplete", function () {
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

### Routes

```
Route::post('store-masseur', [MasseurController::class, 'store'])->name('masseur.add');
```

Comment: Have you ever thought about removing the route from your form tag or removing ajax via js that sends the data?

Comment: Removing the ajax request solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: However, now the text form inputs refuses to save... any ideas?